# Excel Visual Basic variable as HTMLDocument

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, office-2010

A user has sent me a macro that is no longer working and the developer has since retired.  When I look at the variables, one is declared as follows:

```
Public WebDoc As HTMLDocument
```

When I run the macro, it errors out on the line below:

```
For p = 1 To y

 vWBCount = Workbooks.Count

 With ExpApp

     .navigate vPath

      Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
          MyTimer
      Loop

      Set WebDoc = .document    ''''THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR

      For Each IElem In WebDoc.forms(0).elements

                Select Case IElem.Name
                    Case "InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"
                        IElem.Value = vBU(p)

                    Case "InputKeys_bind2"
                        IElem.Value = vBegDate

                    Case "InputKeys_bind3"
                        IElem.Value = vEndDate

                    Case "InputKeys_VENDOR_ID"
                        IElem.Value = vVendor(p)

                End Select
            Next

            .navigate vSubmit

            Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                Call LookForAndCloseIEPopup
                MyTimer
            Loop
```

The error message says:

> Object library feature not supported

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.  The macro is being run on Windows 7 / Office 2010 / Visual Basic.

Thanks......

Comment: Try `Tools -> References -> Microsoft HTML Object Library`

Comment: @Tehscript......Thanks for the suggestions.  I did that and got past the line in error.  Now I'm getting an "An object invoked has disconnected from its client" error message on the line below:

Comment: Set ExpApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ExpApp.Visible = True

With ExpApp
    
    .navigate vLogin
    
    Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE  ' error on this line
        MyTimer
    Loop

Comment: I can't see where you declare ExpApp and the rest of your code in your post. You can  try to add `Tools -> References -> Microsoft Internet Controls` and then declare it as `Dim ExpApp  As InternetExplorer`. Then delete `Set ExpApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` line.

Comment: @tehscript.........That reference was already selected.  I also changed the declaration as you suggested.  Still having issues........

Comment: Well if you keep the rest of the code (where ExpApp takes place) to yourself and describe your problem like "Still having issues...", then my hands are tied, sorry.

Comment: @Tehscript............You are right.  That wasn't a very good description of the issue.  I've gone another route and am no longer using this code.  Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

Use .readyState = 4 instead of .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE. They refer to the same readyState status.

Comment: I faced the same issue and it was solved by the above step.